# How to save the QEMU console output form Windows Host to a file?

Tags: qemu

**Background:**

Host: Win10

Qemu: Qemu 6.0.0

This is my command: `qemu-system-arm.exe -D ./log.txt -M sabrelite -smp 4 -m 1G -nographic -serial null -serial mon:stdio -kernel image -dtb sabrelite.dtb`

I'm using this command to create a Qemu, in order to run some tests with a lot of output logs on it.
I wanna save the outputs to a file.

**Question:**

How can I save the console output from windows host QEMU to a file?

It seems that the `-D ./log.txt` just created an empty file, and did not save the outputs to it.

Answer (score 1):

The -D option is for the log file for the debug info enabled with '-d'. If you don't specify any '-d' options there will be no debug info in the log file.

The output of the serial console is entirely separate. That is controlled by the '-serial' option, which currently you have set up to go to stdio (with a monitor muxed to also use stdio). You can look at the other options for where -serial can be directed; this does include a "send to file", but note that if you just do that then you won't also be able to see it on the console and you won't be able to input anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard windows output redirection. This command line will redirect stdout and stderr to log.txt:

```
qemu-system-arm.exe -M sabrelite -smp 4 -m 1G -nographic -serial null -serial mon:stdio -kernel image -dtb sabrelite.dtb > 1> ./log.txt 2>&1
```